# Traverse a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a problem like this: find all elements in a list such that all element(s) immediately besides it is/are odd numbers.

For example

```
?- find([20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10], L).
L = [20, 2, 4, 6]
```

Normally in other languages I would traverse the list and check the condition, but I don't know how to "think" in Prolog in this scenario. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: a better solution based on CapelliCs suggestion (this uses the `isodd` predicate from below):

```
% if N0 and N2 are odd, cut, add N1 to the result and recurse
ff([N0,N1,N2|T], [N1|R]) :- isodd(N0), isodd(N2), !, ff([N1,N2|T], R).
% for any other case where the list has at least three members, cut and recurse
ff([_,N1,N2|T], R) :- !, ff([N1,N2|T], R).
% this is reached if the list has less that three members - we're done
ff(_, []).

% append and prepend '1' to the list to deal with the edges, call ff.
find(L, R) :- append(L, [1], L1), ff([1|L], R).
```

My old solution which keept track of the two previous values with extra arguments:

```
% isodd(+N)
% helper predicate that succeds for odd numbers.
isodd(N) :- mod(N, 2) =:= 1.

% find(+I, +N1, +N2, +R, -L)
% find/5 is the predicate doing the actual work.
% I is the input list, N1 and N2 are the numbers before the current one,
% R is the intermediate result list and L the result.

% we're done if the input list is empty
find([], _, _, R, R) :- !.

% check if N0 and N2 are odd to see if N1 should be appended to the list.
% if yes, do a cut, append N1 to the result and recurse.
find([N0|T], N1, N2, R, L) :-
   isodd(N0), isodd(N2), !, 
   append(R, [N1], R1), find(T, N0, N1, R1, L).

% if N0 and N2 are not odd (and thus the cut in the previous clause isn't
% reached) just continue the recursion.
find([N0|T], N1, _, R, L) :- find(T, N0, N1, R, L).

% find(+I, -L)
% this predicate is the entry point - initialize the result list and the first
% values for N1 and N2, and append 1 to the input list so we don't need an extra
% predicate for dealing with the last item.
find(I, L) :- append(I, [1], I1), find(I1, 1, 0, [], L).
```

Comment: for the "better" solution, can you explain the two cuts? What are their purposes?

Comment: @Chin, the cuts stop the predicate from overgenerating - The third clause succeds for every possible input list, without the cuts we could backtrack to it at any point during the recursion, thereby generating multiple incorrect answers. This can also be done by rewriting the third clause to only match the case where the input list has exactly two members, or add a cut to the third clause which makes the cuts in the first two clauses unneccessary.

Answer (score 3):

visit the list considering the pair of head elements:

```
find([A,B|R], [A|T]) :-
   is_odd(B),
   ... etc etc
```

You'll need to add obviously the base recursion case and the case when A must be discarded.